# Joining pandas dataframes where indexes have different number of ordered rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

df1 and df2 have rows if scores are 80 or better for a pattern. Each pattern's rows are ordered highest to lowest.

df1:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pattern': ['a','a','b'],'score':[100, 80, 85]})
>>> df1.set_index('pattern',inplace=True)
>>> df1
         score
pattern       
a          100
a           80
b           85
```

df2:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'pattern': ['a','b'],'score':[90, 95]})
>>> df2.set_index('pattern',inplace=True)
>>> df2
         score
pattern       
a           90
b           95
```

I want a merged dataframe where the highest scores for each pattern are on the same row, the second highest scores for each pattern are on the row below, and so on. Any row in df1 or df2 needs to be in merged dataframe. If there are more scores for a pattern in df1, then I want a default value like null, 0, -1 (doesn't matter what) in the cell for df2:

`score_df1  score_df2
pattern

a              100         90
a               80         0
b               85         95`

I can get scores to repeat if df1 has more rows for a pattern than df2 (or vise versa):

`>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])
         score_df1  score_df2
pattern

a              100         90
a               80         90
b               85         95`

But how to get default/null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an outer join:

`pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_df1','_df2'], how='outer')`

[pandas.DataFrame.merge Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)